# Wordpress - Set wp-admin at domain root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wp-admin

Is there a way to set wp-admin at domain-root?
usually you got to wp-admin @ domain.com/wp-admin
I would like to have wp-admin at domain.com

Is this doable and is it done with Htaccess or what is needed?

Comment: please explain clearly

Comment: Usually when you entering a website you goes to the frontend at domain.com. But i would like to get to the wp-admin when I'm entering domain.com, without /wp-admin being displayed in the url.

Comment: `wp-admin` is a subfolder in the standard WordPress installation.  If you want to redirect your user to that folder immediately upon accessing the domain root, you can indeed do that using `.htaccess.`

Comment: How can you achieve that with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by have /wp-admin at your domain root, but you can use this in your theme's functions.php to force a log-in to view the website.

```
// Force user login before viewing website
function force_login()
{
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        if ( is_feed() )
        {
            $credentials = array();
            $credentials['user_login'] = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
            $credentials['user_password'] = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

            $user = wp_signon( $credentials );

            if ( is_wp_error( $user ) )
            {
                header( 'WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '"' );
                header( 'HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized' );
                die();

            } 

        } 

        else
        {

            header( 'Location: /wp-admin' );
            die();

        }

    } 

} 

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'force_login' );
```

Comment: My question is more about getting the url to wp-admin to be domain root. Usually when you entering a website you goes to the frontend at domain.com. But i would like to get to the wp-admin when I'm entering domain.com, without /wp-admin being displayed in the url

Answer (score 0):

You can do redirect from `domain.com/wp-admin` `to domain.com`

but the problem is after you logged in, the url will land on `wp-admin/posts.php` etc., which will redirect it to domain.com again.

By this way it will create a redirect loop which will turn breaking the wp-admin.

I think its a bad idea, instead you can create a custom login page and set it as a homepage.

Comment: What do you mean with custom login page?